# Module '"domhandler"' has no exported member 'DomElement'. Did you mean to use 'import DomElement from "domhandler"' instead?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I trying to build a react-typescript project. ii didn't install dom utils and HTML parser libraries. but when I tried to run yarn build, the following error is coming

```
       ~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/htmlparser2/index.d.ts:17:10 - error TS2614: Module '"domhandler"' has no exported member 'DomElement'. Did you mean to use 'import DomElement from "domhandler"' instead?

17 export { DomElement, DomHandlerOptions, DomHandler, Element, Node } from 'domhandler';
            ~~~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/react-html-parser/index.d.ts:9:10 - error TS2305: Module '"htmlparser2"' has no exported member 'DomElement'.

9 import { DomElement } from "htmlparser2";
```

I tried some of follwoing steps,

added "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.json file

https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html/issues/333 i tried some steps whatever they said, still no use.

tsconfig.json file

```
{
  /* https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html */
  /* https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html */
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs" /* webpack supports imports syntax */,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom", "es2015"],
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* load modules like node */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* to treat commonJS 'module.exports' as 'default export' */,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}
```

This might be a duplicate question. But I don't know how to solve this issue, can someone help me for solving this??

Answer (score 1):

If you have these errors just check your `package.json`.
Possibly you installed unwanted type definitions because `htmlparser2` package has all necessary type definitions from the box.

If so then delete it and use *@Kasunaz*'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by configuring Typescript (editing `tsconfig.json`) to "Skip type checking of declaration files." ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck)):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    ...
  }
}
```